# How to use Chrome's built-in flash instead of Adobe Flash install

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I have flash installed, but I'd like Google Chrome to use it's built-in version of flash, since the adobe version seems to be a worse user experience..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type `about:plugins` in your omnibar. You should get a list of plugins that are enabled/disabled in chrome at the moment. `ctrl + f` for `flash`.

You should see one or more instances of Flash; one of which is bundled with Chrome, and the other the one you had to download manually. Pick which one you want enabled/disabled, then restart the browser.

[image]

Comment: That is correct. Chrome always uses the latest version of Flash that is available regardless of whether it is built-in or standalone. If the built-in one is newer, then there is nothing to do. If the built-in version is older, then you can either disable the standalone one to use the built-in one, or just update Chrome since they always update it to use the latest version within a short time of a new (standalone) release.

Comment: Note that `about:plugins` was deprecated and is no longer available in Chrome version 57 and higher, so this solution will no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome's built-in Flash *is* Adobe Flash. They have merely bundled it with the program rather than having to have you download it separately.

Perhaps if you describe what your real issue is, you can obtain some help with resolving it?

Comment: I know it is using adobe flash, but perhaps they haven't enabled as many security features as I have with my flash install, so I am not bothered with local storage warnings and the like.  They sandbox flash tho, which I don't think is done normally (am I wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to uninstall Adobe Flash, because Google Chrome includes it automatically. The problem is, however, how to fully uninstall Adobe Flash, is a question that I have as well on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/449573/how-to-fully-uninstall-adobe-flash).

I've heard (Unsure about this but quite likely) that its safer to have Adobe Flash on Google Chrome, due to the reasons below:

1. Google is known for rapid updates for Google Chrome. This probably includes security fixes to Flash as well.
2. Google Chrome has sandboxing as a core element of the browser. This may (unsure about the extent of this) include Flash as well.